# GridView onScrollPositionChanged?

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I have a GridView and I want to change somthing, while the user scrolls, when it reaches a certain position. I know we have the onScroll() method of OnScrollListener, but in the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScroll%28android.widget.AbsListView,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) it says:

> This will be called after the scroll has completed

Is there a proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your goal, it seems that [onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScrollStateChanged%28android.widget.AbsListView,%20int%29) method should do what you want.

Then, using [getScrollY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScrollY%28%29) method of your GridView should allow you to check what position are you curretly at.

```
mList.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        int scrollPosition = view.getScrollY();
        // doSomething(scrollPosition)
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that method, but when I read the name I suggested a different behaviour and just didn't read on.

Comment: @grexter89 Yes, i agree that name suggests different behaviour, but description says it should be called before every next frame is rendered.